# I got a object object and cant select the items

Tags: angular

I get a json-Response with values and add this to the interface. But I cant select them in the html-page.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

import gamejson from '../../assets/data/gametest.json';

interface GAMEDETAIL {
  id: number,
  title: string
  releasedate: number
  description: string,
  adddate: string,
  changedate: string,
  pdffile: string,
  youtubelink: string,
  images: any,
  producer: any
  
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game',
  templateUrl: './game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game.component.css']
})

export class GameComponent implements OnInit {

  private data:any = [];  
  gamedetail: GAMEDETAIL[]= [];
  gameid: number = 0;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http:HttpClient) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.gameid = parseInt( this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') as string );
      
      this.getJSON(this.gameid).subscribe(data => {
        this.gamedetail = data;
        console.log(this.gamedetail);
    });
    }

    getJSON(spielid: Number): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get("https://example.org/api/gamedetail/" + spielid);
    }

}
```

Here is the html for this:

```
<h1>{{ gamedetail.dontfindanykey }}</h1>>
```

I can select the gamedetail.title (for example). But i can't select title or description or else. In the log would the complete json be viewed

This is the json-response that I get from the server:

```
    {"id":1,
     "title":"Ligretto",
     "releasedate":2000,
    "producer": 
[{"company":"Schmidt","url":"https:\/\/www.example.de"}],"pdffile":"https:\/\/cdn.example.de","description":"Das ist die Beschreibung zum Spiel","images":[{"position":0,"imagefile":"https:\/\/cdn.example.org"},{"position":1,"imagefile":"https:\/\/cdn.example.org"}],"youtubelink":"https:\/\/example.org","adddate":"2021-12-22 22:22:44","changedate":"2022-01-11 11:11:20"}
```

Comment: Can you make the question a bit clear? I couldn't understand what you're trying to achieve. What do you mean by select? you only use the h1 tag in your HTML. What is the expected result/output etc?

Comment: And just a friendly suggestion, make your variable names camelCase. This is the general convention for typescript/javascript. It will make your code more understandable.

Comment: Hi, i like to output <h1>{{ gamedetail.title }}</h1>

Comment: Can you edit your answer, it's not quite understandable JSON. What is gamedetail data in runtime? basically what is console.log(this.gamedetail);

Comment: https://backend.spielanleitungen-online.de/api/gamedetail/3  here i have the json-Response

Comment: Is there a console error something like cannot read the property title of undefined when you try to use {{ gamedetail.title }} ?

Comment: I cant compile it, i got the error that there is no gamedetail.title

Comment: your `GAMEDETAIL` interface is missing a few commas after `title` and `releasedate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the problematic line;

```
gamedetail: GAMEDETAIL[]= [];
```

gamedetail's type is array, you're assigning object to it. You can't read array.title.

This will solve the problem, gamedetail isn't an array, your response json is object;

```
gamedetail: GAMEDETAIL;
```